# ASP.NET Membership - Search users

Tags: asp.net

How does one perform a search (for example, by user name) on the membership data stored by the default ASP.NET membership provider?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

after this you check if currentUser is null or not

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could import the membership schema into my own database and create the models using Entity Framework. This allows me to search by any fields and criterion I wish.